# Why is a variable declared outside an if block not accessible?

Tags: go

I use a pattern where a variable is declared outside of an if-block and the block determines the value to assign to it.  The compiler does not like the following code and reports: "result declared but not used".  It looks proper to me...  Please explain what I am misunderstanding.

Thank you for your help,
Mike

```
func blah() {
    var result error = nil // "result declared but not used"
    if 1 == 1 {
        result = fmt.Errorf("ouch")
    }
}
```

Comment: It is accessible – that’s why there’s no error on the `result = …` line. But you haven’t used the value assigned to it.

Comment: Arggg!  Makes sense...   I assumed that the result = fmt.Errorf() would account for using it.  Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: You're "using it" to store a value, but you never used the stored value - assignment doesn't count as 'use'.

Answer (score 0):

**Assigning a value into a variable is not using that variable**. 
*This is also an error (here compiler never read the variable so it's not used)* .

```
var result string  // "result declared but not used"
result = "sheikh"
```

"Every declared variable have to be used" means compiler have to **read** the value of that variable and use it to perform at least one operation (**arithmetic Operation** or **assignment Operation** or **Unary Operation** or **Relational Operation**)

*This is not an error,*

```
var result int
result+=1
```

*This is not an error,*

```
var result int  
result=1
if result == 1 {
}
```

*If you want to avoid this error simply do this,*

```
var result int 
result=1
_=result
```